# Keyboard shortcut moving windows to the side no longer work

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I had installed the gnome extension WinTile. Not being satisfied I removed it again, but since
then the original shortcuts to move windows, like the terminal etcetera, to the left or right no longer function.

I have searched the web but I found no resource describing how to restore this functionality.

How can i best restore the original functionality of the Ctrl+Super+Left/Right Arrow?
I am using ubuntu 20.04.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please note that the default keybindings for tiling left or right are <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>, and not, as you suggest, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>. The latter are not assigned in a default Ubuntu install. So first check whether the former keys work as expected. If not, you may indeed need to restore the default settings.

To restore the default behaviour of these key bindings, issue following terminal commands, which reset the configuration to default:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right
```

Comment: Indeed you're right, my mind was twisted I guess, however the gsettings commands might come in handy in the future for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You  might be better using the GNOME extension `Put Windows`

[image]

In your browser enter `https://extensions.gnome.org/` in the address bar and search for the extension.

I use this extension all the time in 20.04 having previously used it in 18.04 and it's quite functional in that you can define the size of the windows width and height, the keyboard shortcuts, Move Focus and application based size and location settings.

[image]

[image]

I tried it with the terminal window and it performs just fine.